# Remembering Dynamic/AJAX Form Values

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

Before I start I'm sorry if this has been asked before, however most of the answers I have read have either not worked or are not clear enough.

My first question is how does the browser remember form input values? I.E, you go to GMail and start typing your E-Mail address in and a dropdown appears with the E-Mails that have been typed into your computer. I do KNOW that this is just handled natively by the browser, however how or can I make it work with dynamic/AJAX forms? How does the page's Cache-Control or other headers come into play with this? Or do they at all?

My second question is related, on some web pages when you login the browser (not the website) asks if you would like it to remember your name and password. If you do then the next time you go to the login page the form is filled out for you already in a gold highlight. How can I replicate this behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to save typed in email addresses you will need some sort of database. You would use ajax to record the keystrokes to the database and then retrieve it with ajax. That can be does simultaneously with ajax.

The second question is you need to store a cookie with an id so that you can use the to look up the information in a database and either fill in the username or just log them in.